# (Phonegap) javascript trigger event when gps location in range

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, gps, location

I'm working on trying to trigger an event (to unhide an alert or image) based on gps coordinates falling within a certain range.

I think I need to do something like: If GPS Lat is > x (set based on location I want them to go to) and < y & GPS Long is > z and < a, then show (use js change css to display: block).

Am I down the right path?  I'll post what I have as the basics of getting the GPS coordinates to just appear.  I'm learning as I go here, so any help is appreciated for the proper structure.  Thank you.

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var watchID = null;

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = { timeout: 100000 };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                        '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
}

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

UPDATE:

I have gotten to the point where I'm not getting errors, now I'm hoping for some help to get a heading based on my current location and the destination.  Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm posting my current code below:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var watchID = null;
var gpscoord = null;
var destLat = 37.200401
var destLon = 93.278610

function onDeviceReady() {
    var gpsOptions = { timeout: 5000 };
    gpscoord = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gpsSuccess, gpsError, gpsOptions);
}

//gpsSuccess
//
function gpsSuccess(position) {
    var lat = document.getElementById('latitude');
    var lon = document.getElementById('longitude');
    lat.innerHTML = 'Latitude:' + position.coords.latitude;
    lon.innerHTML = 'Longitude:' + position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('gotoLat').innerHTML = 'Destination Latitude: ' + destLat;
    document.getElementById('gotoLon').innerHTML = 'Destination Longitude: ' + destLon;
}

function gpsError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

<div class="container">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p id="latitude">Watching latitude...</p>
        <p id="longitude">Watching longitude...</p>
        <br/>
        <p id="gotoLat">Destination latitude...</p>
        <p id="gotoLon">Destination longitude...</p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that looks fine. The watcher will call onSuccess when the GPS has been successfully polled, and returns data.

I would save the Longitude and Latitude in the global scope, and then you can perform what ever kind of logic you want on it.

Comment: So I'm rearranging things a bit to make it more in line what what I'm needing to do: